# Maximum limit of connections in pooled db?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I was using mysql with python 2.7.I used the following command to create pool of database connections:`pool = PooledDB(mysql.connector, pool_size,database=MYSQL_DB, user=MYSQL_USER, host=MYSQL_HOST,password=MYSQL_PASS)`. There are different threads which take a `dedicated`
connection from this pool.But making `pool_size` to about 50 gives the error:`To many
database connections`. How many connections can I create like this ,If it can't go above a limit I will have to share them between threads(not dedicated any more). In what cases
sharing database connections between threads is not appropriate??

Comment: What do you get if you run the query `SELECT @@max_connections;` on your database server?

Comment: @Aya 34 it is!!! so can I use all 34 and I create over 100 of threads and give a dedicated connection to each so now I have to give shared!! will it give any problems ??

Comment: @Aya it gives to many connections for 22 also !!!!

Comment: Bear in mind those 34 are shared with all other clients which might be using the database. Might be simplest just to increase the number of `max_connections` in the server configuration.

Comment: ok! will do so any ideas about sharing connections amongst the threads is it healthy?

Comment: Depends on the [`threadsafety`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety) value for the DB module. For the one I use, `import MySQLdb; print MySQLdb.threadsafety` prints `1`, so "Threads may share the module, but not connections." If you're using a connection pool, then you only need as many threads as you need concurrent connections. Given the reality of disk I/O constraints, a DB can only run so many queries in parallel without thrashing the disk to the point where overall performance is degraded. 100 connections may be too many, so try experimenting with different values.

Comment: print 1 for me as well.So does it mean I have to give a dedicated connection per thread ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32967/discussion-between-sasha-sami-and-aya)